# The midpoint of one diagonal in a parallelogram is also the midpoint of another

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

If ABCD is a parallelogram and M is the midpoint of AC, prove that M is also the midpoint of BD.

*I think vectors must be used to solve this problem*

I know that this is part of the definition of a parallelogram but this question is assuming that you don't know that and therefore proving it's true.

Comment: What is your definition of a parallelogram?

Comment: The characteristics of a parallelogram hold i.e. a quadrilateral with opposite sides parallel of equal magnitude. I think this question wants to use vectors so no angle work.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hint (from the figure)

$$
DM=MB \qquad and \qquad CM=AM
$$

Comment: I think I can only use vectors to prove that M is the midpoint of BD

Comment: If you want you can... but if $MB=MD$ than $M$ is, by definition, the mid pont :)

Comment: I know what you mean but I  think this question is actually calling to prove the definition part of it

Answer (score 0):

See emilios figure so i continue from there sorry dunno how to add pictures.$|DM|+|MC|=|DC|$.(1).(triangle law of vectors. And $|AM|+|MB|=|AB|$..(2) but $|AB|=|DC|$. .. opposite sides of parallelogram are equal thus $|DM|+|MC|=|AM|+|MB|$.. from 1,2 but$|AM|=|MC|$ M is the midppint thus $|DM|=|MB|$ which implies M is also the midpoint of diagonal BD.

Comment: How can you conclude that DM+MC=AM+MB when only magnitude of the vectors i.e. |AB|=|DC| has been proven? To make the vectors equal, don't you need to have the same direction as well? Thanks

Comment: I have edited here we want magnitudes only not directions and signs. Thanks!