# Coordinate Geometry parallelogram question

Tags: geometry

! [OABC is a parallelogram where O is the origin and B is the point (5,7). C lies on the line x - 2y=0 and A lies on the line 2x - y=0. Calculate the coordinates of A and C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7BTM.png)

Comment: You have a question, and if you post it here, you've probably attempted, and failed, to solve it yourself. It is much easier for others to judge the most appropriate "level" for an answer to your question if you provide these attempts. So you'll receive answers better suited to your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

WLOG $A(2a,a); C(c,2c)$

Now the mid point of $OB$ should coincide with that of $AC$ as [The midpoint of one diagonal in a parallelogram is also the midpoint of another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549988/the-midpoint-of-one-diagonal-in-a-parallelogram-is-also-the-midpoint-of-another)

Also $OA\parallel BC, OB\parallel AC$

Parallel lines have the same gradient